# what is the most lucrative advertisement combination

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an interview question. I don't know how to solve it. Please help me to solve. 
Problem: Let us consider there is a 3X3 advertisement block in a website.  We have a database table, populated by a 3rd party vendor, which has plenty of advertisements varying from size 1X1 and 3X3. **We have to derive an algorithm to fetch the most lucrative advertisement combination at any given point of time (i.e.) find the advertisement combination with fits the entire 3X3 block and the combination must be the most profitable one.** 
Eg. Consider the following data with the entries as advertisements

```
size price
3X3  3000
1X3  1000
2X3  2500
```

In the above, though there is an advertisement of size 3X3 which could fit in our block perfectly, using it would fetch us 3000 bucks but if we opt to use row# 2 and 3, we can easily fill our block and also get 3500 which is greater than using the 3X3 advertisement. If there is a new entry as shown below,

```
size price
3X3  3000
1X3  1000
2X3  2500
3X3  5000
```

the more optimum solution would be to use row number 4.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I wonder if you could rank them by Price/per square and keep trying from the "top" of that ranking until 3x3 is full. There'll be times when you have to back out a chosen one because it cannot "fit".

Comment: Hi,do you find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It could be solved by [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), first find best `1X1` then best `2X1` is either from two of best `1X1` or one `2X1`. best `2X2` is either from two best `2X1` or one `2X2` and ... you just save the best `xXy` block and continue the calculation, for `3X1` then `3X2` then at last for best `3X3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the solution here https://github.com/loganathan-s/lucarative_ad (Written in RUBY)

Comment: You put the whole stuffs here in the answer. That will be good idea.